# MenuItem from template refreshes current page

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I do not know if this is the default behavior but it is frustrating me. I have some pages that use the same pageTemplate. Within page template I have a MenuItem that is used to display an information popup. The problem is that whenever the popup is opened, whenever I click the menuItem, the page where I am located gets refreshed! I have removed the partial submit from the MenuItem and nothing changed. Is there a way to make the page not to refresh in this case?

Comment: If you use pageTemplate, probably you use regions to display content? So may be region are being updated by some event. You need to provide more detail regarding this case, like page code and so on. And partial submit (ajax calls) actually help you to avoid unwanted refreshes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution and the problem. I was calling the popup programatically, and for some strange reason this was refreshing the iterator on the page. I made the popup calling through "showPopupBehavior" operation and everything got resolved.